# Check if a list is sorted in javascript using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In javascript (underscore) , how do I test whether a list of numbers is already sorted or not?

Comment: @Esailija I am trying to implement a unit test like "should the array be sorted"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `_.every` to check whether all elements are in order:

```
_.every(arr, function(value, index, array) {
  // either it is the first element, or otherwise this element should 
  // not be smaller than the previous element.
  // spec requires string conversion
  return index === 0 || String(array[index - 1]) <= String(value);
});
```

Comment: If there's a sort that can handler the `NaN` values, then its comparator could be used.

Comment: @Pointy: I'm reading the specs and it appears that in case of `NaN`, its string representation is used. It's not just `<=` unfortunately. I'll edit.

Comment: It turned out not to be much more complicated in fact.

Comment: Using a string representation doesn't work if you have an array like `[ 8, 9, 10]` for example, because `"9" <= "10"` is `false`.

Comment: +1 for `_.every`. -1 for `String(value)`. Something like `function nansFirst(value){return isNan(value) ? -Infinity : value;}` and `... <= nansFirst(value)` would be fine.
Or having a comparator like Pointy was pointing out and doing `nansFirstComparetor(prevValue, value) <= 0`

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to simply iterate over the list, examining whether each element is smaller than its next neighbor:

```
function is_sorted(arr) {
    var len = arr.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var last = undefined,
    sorted = true;
_.forEach(arr, function(val) {
    if(last !== undefined && val < last) sorted = false;
    last = val;
});
alert(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this very helpful [link](https://gist.github.com/yorkie/7959685).

```
/*
* check the array is sorted
* return: if sorted in ascending ->  1
*         if sorted in descending -> -1
*         not sorted  ->  0
*/

Array.prototype.isSorted = function() {
  return (function(direction) {
  return this.reduce(function(prev, next, i, arr) {
    if (direction === undefined)
      return (direction = prev <= next ? 1 : -1) || true;
    else
      return (direction + 1 ?
        (arr[i-1] <= next) : 
        (arr[i-1] >  next));
    }) ? Number(direction) : false;
  }).call(this);
}

var arr = [3,2,1,0];
arr.isSorted(); // Will return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple es6 code:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [3, 2, 1]

function isSorted (arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).every((item, i) => arr[i] <= item)
}

console.log(isSorted(arr), isSorted(arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in pure js with *every*:

```js
//Array is sorted
[1, 2, 3].every( (item, i, arr) => i < arr.length - 1 ? arr[i] < arr[i + 1] : arr[i] ); //true
[3, 2, 1].every( (item, i, arr) => i < arr.length - 1 ? arr[i] < arr[i + 1] : arr[i] ); //false

//Equolent
[1, 2, 3].every( (item, i, arr) => i > 0 ? arr[i] > arr[i - 1] : arr[i] < arr[i + 1] ); //true
```