# Validate if the last value of array is greater than previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with value, `[0,3,4,6,0]`, How do I validate if the before values is less than the after values?

```
var array = [0,3,4,6,0];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   //if the value of 0 >,3 >,4, > 6
   //return false;
}
```

I need to require the user to enter an ordered sequence of numbers like `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`.  Hence, I need to validate if the enter is not in an ordered sequence.

Comment: You could find helpful this: [check if a list is sorted in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914982/check-if-a-list-is-sorted-in-javascript)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641569/find-if-array-contains-5-consecutive-numbers-with-javascript

Comment: You can use `Array#every` https://jsfiddle.net/r771nqcb/

Comment: One line solution, if the array is not too large:  (array.toString() == array.slice(0).sort().reverse())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution in ES5 using [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
function customValidate(array) {
  var length = array.length;
  return array.every(function(value, index) {
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    return nextIndex < length ? value <= array[nextIndex] : true;
  });
}
console.log(customValidate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(customValidate([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(customValidate([0, 0, 0, 4, 5]));
console.log(customValidate([0, 0, 0, 2, 1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate all the array, expect true until you reach a false, where you can break out of the loop.

```js
function ordered(array) {
  var isOk = true; // Set to true initially

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
      // If something doesn't match, we're done, the list isn't in order
      isOk = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.write(isOk + "<br />");
}

ordered([]);
ordered([0, 0, 0, 1]);
ordered([1, 0]);
ordered([0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5]);
ordered([5, 0, 4, 1, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to loop the array and compare adjacent elements like this:

```
var isOk = false;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        isOk = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thus flag `isOk` will ensure that the whole array is sorted in descending order.

Comment: Maybe `>=`, otherwise `[0,0,0,1]` would fail wouldn't it? Edit: Wait, wont that only ever check the first two?

Comment: Why `int i = 0`; ? It's javascript, not java. Why breaking the first time you get the condition true?

Answer (score 1):

```
        function inOrder(array){

            for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){

                if((array[i] < array[i+1]))
                    return false;

            }
            return true;
        }
```