# Validating array sequence value except the zero 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array validating if values are ordered by descending or not. However, if the sequence have a value of 0 it interrupt the process and returns false instead of true. How do i avoid the 0 value and continue the process as descending. https://jsfiddle.net/snb3p0qy/1/

```
function customValidate(array) {
    var length = array.length;
    return array.every(function(value, index) {
        var nextIndex = index + 1;
        return nextIndex < length ? value >= array[nextIndex] : true;
    });
}
document.write(customValidate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
document.write(customValidate([5, 0, 3, 2, 1]));//This supposed to be true
document.write(customValidate([0, 0, 0, 4, 5]));
document.write(customValidate([0, 0, 0, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: And this is a perfect example of why people should just use a for loop when they want to iterate over an array.

Comment: the second and the last arrays should be true?

Comment: @naortor yes it should be

Comment: @bhspencer I disagree. Using a `for` loop is not needed in very many cases. The problem isn't that a loop wasn't used but that the wrong way to check the array was used - `every` and `forEach` and others could do surrounding lookups but are generally not very good at them.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework question? Answer copy-pasted from this recently (like 2 hours before) similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427784/592253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay with your `every` approach you could filter out the `0` before doing the test.

```
function customValidate(array) {
  'use strict'
  return array.filter(item => item != 0).every(function(value, index, filteredArray) {
    // instead of referencing the original array the filtered
    // array that is pass as third argument to every is used
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    return nextIndex < filteredArray.length ? value >= filteredArray[nextIndex] : true;
  });
}
```

But the downside of that approach is that you will create a new temporary array. So for large data this approach would not scale well.

A better idea would be to use a regular loop to test it. Probably something like that (this is for sure not the best code):

```
function customValidate(array) {
 'use strict'
  var length = array.length;
  // set i to the index of the first value that is not 0
  var i = array.findIndex(value => value != 0); 
  var lastItem = array[i];

  i++;
  // after the first item was found, loop to the end of the list
  while (i < length) {
    // if the current item is not 0 then do the compare otherwise skip the test.
    if (array[i] != 0) {
      if (array[i] > lastItem) {
        return false;
      }
      lastItem = array[i];
    }
    i++;
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)  is not supported in all browsers yet, but you can use the polyfill shown on the MDN site, or replace it with a loop.

**EDIT** I had an error in the `filter` example, because the filtered array has to be used as reference.

Answer (score 2):

try the following return statement

```
return nextIndex < length ? value === 0 || value >= array[nextIndex] : true;
```

or even

```
return nextIndex >= length || value === 0 || value >= array[nextIndex];
```

so I edited the code just to make it work for [ 5 , 0 , 1 ] scenario **but of course it will be much better to use a for loop like the second answer**.

```
while (array[nextIndex] === 0 && nextIndex < length) {
    nextIndex++;
}
return nextIndex >= length || value === 0 || value >= array[nextIndex];
```

Comment: I was wrong about my last stament, because in my test I had changed your third example slightly to  `[0, 0, 4, 0, 5]` and for this it won't work, because it will not test `4`  against `5`  because each interleaving `0` stops the test @RaffyTLawrence

Comment: so I edited the answer just to make it work, but @t.niese answer is better.