# How to verify whether an array members are consecutive or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I verify whether array members are "continuous" or not?

As an example, Array [1,3,4,5,6] is not a continuous array as it is missing number 2 in between which will complete the increasing order sequence. Which JavaScript array methods can be a good candidate for this kind of validation?

I have tried JavaScript array methods such as ".map", ".every", ".some", but with no luck.

```
   let values = [1,3,4,5,6];

   let result1 = values.map(x => x > 5);
   console.log('value of result1 : ', result1);
   Result: "value of result1 : ", [false, false, false, false, true]

   let result2 = values.some(x => x > 5);
   console.log('value of result2 : ', result2);
   Result: "value of result2 : ", true
   
   let result5 = values.every(x => x > 4);
   console.log('value of result5 : ', result5);
   Result: "value of result5 : ", false
```

Thanks...

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39427784/1524756

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function every with of as code:

```
values.every((num, i) => i === values.length - 1 || num === values[i + 1] -1 )
```

```js
let values = [1,3,4,5,6];
console.log(values.every((num, i) => i === values.length - 1 || num === values[i + 1] -1 ));
```

Comment: You're welcome. If possible vote as the correct answer :)

Comment: Strange, the was not green signaled here.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop can also help.

```js
function continuos(arr) {
  let prev = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (prev + 1 !== arr[i]) return false;
    prev = arr[i];
  }
  return true;
}

let values = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(continuos(values));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for any JavaScript method here, which Renato Sant'Anna's answer has helped.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fast and easy to understand:

```
const isConsecutive = (array) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== array[i - 1] + 1) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

We start at index 1 and compare the current element with the previous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for any JavaScript method here, which Renato Sant'Anna's answer has helped.
Thanks.

Comment: @AbhayDesai There's no native method that does this. If you're looking for a single expression, you could use an IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

`slice` then use `some`, utilizing the fact that the index is passed as the second argument:

```js
values.slice(1).some((v, i) => v != values[i] + 1)
```

Comment: @canon My code works by checking each element against the previous and making sure it's exactly one greater. The slice ensures the first element isn't checked, since there's no previous element. The slice causes the indices to be shifted already, so the element that **was** element 1 will receive 0 as its index argument, which means you can directly compare with `values[i]` instead of `values[i - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using reduce just for fun, don't use this in your actual codebase or the next person to come along will want to gouge your eyes out.

```
const increasing = arr.reduce(([p, v], c) => ([c, (c >= p) && v]), [arr[0], true])[1]
```